# Releasing Media Player while preparing is causing app to freeze

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have two activities a main activity which has Recyclerview and a detailedActivity which is launched every time the user clicks on one of the items of the Recyclerview. The detailedActivity has a mediaplayer component that is being created everytime a detailedActivity is created. Now in the onDestroy method I always free the resources taken by the mediaPlayer by this code:

```
@Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();}

        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer=null;
    }


    super.onDestroy();
}
```

The app freezes for a while every time I click the back button while the mediaplayer is still preparing. The message that I get in the logcat is this:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

So this freezing only happens if I destroyed the activity while it is preparing but if it is already in the prepared state it won't happen. I use prepreAsync to fetch the media from the internet.
Thanks. Any help is highly appreciated. I have been stuck in this problem for days!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I've kind of worked around the problem. I am writing this for anyone who might encounter the same situation as I did. I made two boolean flags in the scope of the class like this:

```
 boolean prepared = false;
 boolean cancel = false;
```

After that in the onpreapred method I set prepared to true.

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            prepared = true;

        }
    });
```

In the onDestroy method I check whether the mediaplayer is already prepared or not if prepared I release it from the method its self.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    if (prepared) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
        cancel = true;

    }


    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Otherwise, I set cancel to true and implement on OnBufferingUpdateListener interface and override its method and release the mediaplayer from there.

```
@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

    if (cancel) {
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
        Log.i("msg", " mp released");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove rechecking if mediaplayer is running or not.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    mMediaPlayer.release();
  }
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

If it still happens, try to remove checking mediaplayer in your onDestroy().

-- UPDATE --

This could be related with this bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=959

This could be a help:
[Android MediaPlayer reset freezes UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631998/android-mediaplayer-reset-freezes-ui)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried that but it is not working. I believe the problem is located somewhere in the preparing process. The sudden destroying of the activity while preparing is causing this. I don't know how to solve it yet though.